# setting Dropdown value by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I have tried various method But None of them seems to be working ..

My I Dropdown is Autocomplete , I have used "select2" plugin for that

this is my dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownList(Model.deptProp, new SelectList(Bmsa.UI.Utility.Utility.GetAllDepartments(Model.countryCode), "Value", "Text", Model.deptId), new { onchange = "Getarrnds();" })
```

this is JQUery function

```
 function loadMap(qStr){

   Alert($('select[name$=deptId]').val()); //this is working fine, Getting Value from Dropdown

   // Following Methods are not working
    var deptId=3;
    $("select[name$=deptId]").val(deptId);
    $("select[name$=deptId]").get(0).selectedIndex = deptId;
    $('select[name$=deptId]').val(deptId).attr("selected", "selected");
    $('select[name^="deptId"] option:selected').attr("selected",deptId);
    $('select[name^="deptId"] option[Index="3"]').attr("selected","selected");


}
```

this is parsed HTML

```
<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-deptId-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-deptId-container" title="Select below">Select below</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span>
```

What can I Try More to set value

Comment: Will you mind sharing parsed html ?

Comment: you should rebind select2 after setting value.

Comment: try `$("select[name$=deptId]").val(deptId).trigger("change");`

Comment: it tells error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Did you found a fix for the above mentioned "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error. I am facing the same when using "trigger(change)".

Answer (score 0):

you need to trigger manually change event.
taking from https://select2.github.io/examples.html

```
 $("select[name$=deptId]").val(deptId).trigger("change")
```

Comment: it tells error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded –